# Erro ao interpretar caracteres especiais

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

estou procurando um elemento, e até ai tudo certo, ja testei outras vezes e fucionou, porem.. ao usar esse código

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-qtip="Configurações"]').click()
```

da um erro, e o cmd me retorna

```
  File "chrome.py", line 105, in tearDown
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-qtip="Configura├º├Áes"]').click()
```

claramente ele nao ta achando por que está desconfigurado o "configurações"

esse mesmo elemento, funciona normalmente

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-qtip="Sem descrição."]').click()
```

adicionei no código

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

porem o problema persiste, como proceder?

Comment: Tente colocar assim: `r'//*[@data-qtip="Configurações"]'`, perceba o `r` antes da string. Ou então é `u`, to tentando lembrar.

Comment: ainda continua, qual seria a função do r?

Comment: Ah não, o `r` é para desconsiderar o `\ ` como um caracter especial, tipo `\n` para nova linha ou `\t` para TAB. Tentou com o `u`? To pesquisando aqui nesse momento. Eu já passei por isso mas não to conseguindo reproduzir agora.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings

Comment: u também não funcionou, engraçado que acima uso o mesmo xpath com o campo "Sem Descrição" e funciona perfeitamente,

Comment: Poderia mostrar como tá o trecho que funcionou?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-qtip="Sem descrição."]').click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira que consegui resolver:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Conf').click()
```

porém ainda não consegui entender por que daquela maneria não funiona.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique que o seu arquivo .py está salvo como Unicode (UTF-8) e não ASCII/ANSI. Além disso eu usaria o prefixo `u` na string: `u'//*[@data-qtip="Configurações"]'`

Comment: está sendo salvo corretamente, editei a pergunta com um exemplo parecido que está funcionado, mas em teoria não devia.

Comment: Mas peraí. Você colocou a linha do erro, mas qual é a *mensagem* de erro?

Comment: tem na pergunta.  File "chrome.py", line 105, in tearDown
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-qtip="Configura├º├Áes"]').click()

Comment: Isso não é uma mensagem de erro é só a linha do erro. Sem saber qual o erro mesmo fica difícil descobrir o problema. A maioria das respostas, inclusive a minha, imaginou que fosse um erro de _encoding_ só porque o texto do stack trace ficou corrompido, mas isso pode ser apenas um problema da linha de comando ou da ferramenta usada para imprimir o erro. O erro mesmo pode não ter nada a ver com encoding.